# Nginx RTMP streaming is not reaching the RTMP endpoint

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, azure-media-services

I'm trying to redirect an RTMP streaming from my pc into Ngninx using the [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) following the [examples](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Examples#forward-live-broadcast-service) to redirect the stream into an Azure Media Service live event. But it won't detect the encoder. I'm using the following nginx.conf:

```
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            push rtmp://d-myamsacc-usct.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/x4t/x4t;
        }
    }
}
```

My OBS is configured to stream to rtmp://191.123.1.72/live with a stream key "test" and using a local VLC I can see the stream if I use rtmp://191.123.1.72/live/test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push URL should be like below. It works for me.

```
application live {
        live on;
        record off;
        push rtmp://d-myamsacc-usct.channel.media.azure.net:1935 app=live/x4t/x4t;
}
```

My sample url is `push rtmp://p***2-p**imediaservices-usso.channel.media.azure.net:1935 app=live/3b5e8425**********50449d57d379d;`.

[image]

For more details, you can [see answer in this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-forum/unable-to-use-nginx-rtmp-streaming-server-with-stream/m-p/1282783#M4608).

Comment: thanks! Just note that instead of app=live/x4t/x4t; I used app=live/x4t; and it worked 

Comment: Yes, you should only need the one "Stream Key" path which can be anything really as long as you have the full GUID path first to the channel.